# ggraph network plot: specify node coordinates

Tags: r, networking, cartesian-coordinates, ggraph, ggforce

Trying to plot a network with the `ggraph` package and specify the coordinates of each node. While I can implement this with the `igraph` package - I cannot do this with the `ggraph` package.

```
# reproducible example to generate a random graph
library(igraph)
g1 <- erdos.renyi.game(20, 1/2)
plot(g1)

# function to produce coordinates for each node in order of the node
# degree (number of links per node)
coord <- function(g){   
    n.nod <- length(V(g))
    mat.c <- matrix(0, nrow = n.nod, ncol = 2)
    deg <- degree(g)
    uniq.deg <- unique(deg)
    min.d <- min(deg); max.d<- max(deg)
    spa <- 10/(max.d - min.d) # how much to increment 0 to 10 space along y-axis

    divi.y.1 <- seq(from = min.d, to=max.d, by = 1)
    divi.y.2 <- seq(from = 0, to=10, by = spa)  # both have same length

    ind.x <- c(); ind.x[1] = 0
    for(x in 2:n.nod){
      ind.x[x] <- ind.x[x-1] + 0.1
      if(ind.x[x] >= 10){
        ind.x[x] = ind.x[x-1] - 0.1
      }  
    } 
 d1 <- data.frame(divi.y.1, divi.y.2)

 # plotting space of grid is (0,0), (0, 10), (10, 10), (10, 0)
 for(i in 1:n.nod){
    # y-axis in order
    inD <-  which(d1$divi.y.1 == deg[i])
    mat.c[i, 2] <- d1[inD,2]
 } 
 mat.c[, 1] <- ind.x
 return(data.frame(mat.c))
}
```

Here is the "old fashioned" way of plotting the `igraph` object:

```
# plot igraph object - the old fashion way
x11()
plot(g1, layout = coord(g1), rescale = T, frame=T,
 vertex.frame.color = "black", edge.color = "lightsteelblue",
 edge.width = 1, vertex.label.cex = 1,
 vertex.label.color = "black", 
 main = "Nodes in order of degree: top have more links, bottom fewer links")
```

Link to `ggraph` documentation is [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggraph/versions/0.1.1). Please also see GitHub repository for `ggraph` for package installation instructions (need >R.3.3 version). Below is the ggraph plot that works (but I haven't specified the coordinates for each node):

```
library(ggraph)
V(g1)$NaMe <- seq(1:20)

x11()
   ggraph(g1, 'igraph', algorithm = 'kk') +  
   geom_edge_link(colour = "black", alpha = 0.8, show.legend = F) + 
   geom_node_label(aes(label = NaMe)) + ggtitle("ggraph plot: How to allocate coordinate for each node?") + 
   ggforce::theme_no_axes()
```

Here is my attempt to make the `ggraph` plot with specified coordinates for each node. Following similar examples and earlier attempts in `ggraph()` where coordinates of the nodes are passed onto the plot, I tried the following:

```
g <- make_ring(10) + make_full_graph(5)
coords <- layout_(g, as_star())
plot(g, layout = coords)
# try to replicate this example:
coords2 <- add_layout_(g1, coord(g1))
```

Also tried using [this function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggraph/versions/0.1.1/topics/layout_igraph_manual). It is difficult because there is not an example in the documentation.

```
Lay <- layout_igraph_manual(g1, coord(g1))
Lay <- layout_igraph_igraph(g1, coord(g1))

x11()
ggraph(g1, 'igraph', algorithm = 'kk' ) + add_layout_(Lay) +
# layout_igraph_circlepack() + 
geom_edge_link(colour = "black", alpha = 0.8, show.legend = F) + 
geom_node_label(aes(label = NaMe)) + ggtitle("ggraph plot: Cannot allocate    coordinate for each node") + 
ggforce::theme_no_axes()
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe it is the author's intention that you call `layout_igraph_manual` directly. If you name the layout as "manual" you can pass in the arguments you need to layout the vertices manually. This got me what you are after, if I understand it correctly:

```
coords <- coord(g1)
names(coords) <- c("x","y")
coords <- as.data.frame(coords)

ggraph(g1, layout = "manual", circular = FALSE, node.positions = coords)+
  geom_edge_link(colour = "black", alpha = 0.8, show.legend = F) + 
  geom_node_label(aes(label = NaMe)) + ggtitle("ggraph plot: How to allocate coordinate for each node?") + 
  ggforce::theme_no_axes()
```

According to the documentation it is important that your manual layout is a dataframe and contains the columns `x` and `y`. I have done this to the output of your `coord()` function. You probably just want to update it to return the data in that form.

Answer (score 1):

You generally don't have to think about node coordinates when using ggraph - they are supplied automatically based on the chosen layout. If you want to calculate the layout yourself beforehand, just use the manual layout - check the documentation for `layout_igraph_manual`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @ThomasP85 (wow! the developer for ggraph). In this instance I wanted to specify the coordinates for each of the nodes. I've tried `layout_igraph_manual`, `layout_`, `add_layout_` and many others and did not seem to work.

What did work was this

```
co2<- data.frame(coord(g1))  # my mistake above, the output of coord() should be a matrix
colnames(co2)<- c("x", "y")
Lay<- createLayout(g1, layout = "nicely") # try any layout
Lay$x<- co2$x  # <== now overwrite their coordinates
Lay$y<- co2$y


x11()  # <==== this is ggraph version of the igraph plot above 
ggraph(graph=g1, data=Lay) + 
geom_edge_link(colour = "black", alpha = 0.5, show.legend = F) + 
geom_node_label(aes(label = NaMe)) + ggtitle("Nodes with higher degree at top, lower degree nodes at the bottom") + 
ggforce::theme_no_axes()
```

@ThomasP85 if you can provide a working example with the code above using `layout_igraph_manual`, it would be much appreciated.