# about how to get fixed network graphs

Tags: r, ggraph

In igraph, by using layout.fruchterman.reingold(), we can apply fixed nodes position. How can we apply same fixed position using ggraph ??

I would like to have fixed nodes position in several network graphs using same samples with different types data.

```
# library
library(igraph)
set.seed(1)
# create data:
links <- data.frame(
  source=c("A","A", "A", "A", "A","J", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D","I"),
  target=c("B","B", "C", "D", "J","A","E", "F", "G", "H", "I","I"),
  weight=(sample(1:20, 12, replace=T))

)
links$weight
nodes <- data.frame(
  name=LETTERS[1:10],
  carac=c( rep("young",3),rep("adult",2), rep("old",5))
)

# Turn it into igraph object
network <- graph_from_data_frame(d=links, vertices=nodes, directed=F) 

# Make a palette of 3 colors
library(RColorBrewer)
coul  <- brewer.pal(3, "Set1") 

# Create a vector of color
my_color <- coul[as.numeric(as.factor(V(network)$carac))]

library(ggraph)
library(tidygraph)
#

g1<-tbl_graph(nodes, links, directed = FALSE)
coords <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(g1)
# igraph
plot(g1,layout=coords)

#
ggraph(g1, layout = "fr", weights = weight) +geom_edge_density(aes()) +
  geom_edge_link(aes(), alpha = 0.3)+
  geom_node_point()+geom_node_point(aes(colour =carac ),size=6)+
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name),size=4, repel = F) +
  theme_graph()
```

Does ggraph have a similar function??

I would deeply appreciate your help.

Comment: Are the two code blocks identical? I can't spot the difference.

Comment: In igraph, we can specify  
coords <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(g1)
# igraph
plot(g1,layout=coords)

How can I do this in ggraph??

Comment: That's not what I mean. I (think I) understand your question. But what's the difference between the `ggraph` methods from the first and second code block?

Comment: I editted the post.

Comment: Like this? https://github.com/thomasp85/ggraph/issues/1 Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/42048671/5325862